# Leer datos de MySql desde Android en tiempo real

Tags: mysql, android, android-studio

Estoy realizando un proyecto para la universidad que consta de dos partes, la primera en leer datos de sensores de temperatura, humedad entre otros con Arduino y guardarlo en una base de datos MySql, esto ya esta realizado.
La segunda parte trata de leer esos datos guardados en la base de datos y mostrarlo en una aplicación Android en tiempo real.

Hasta el momento realizo consultas a la base de datos cada dos segundos mediante un Thread.

```
final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            leerDatos();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                run();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

pero se que esta no es la forma correcta de hacerlo, quisiera saber como debería de hacerlo o las tecnologías que podría implementar.

Comment: Es demasiado amplia tu pregunta, "Edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico, con el suficiente nivel de detalle para permitir identificar una respuesta adecuada. Evita preguntar varias cosas distintas a la vez. Visita la página Cómo preguntar para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta.· revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: quien te dijo que  no es una forma correcta de hacerlo? la mayoría utiliza: new Handler() para ejecucion..